# Centered Slides images

Tags: jquery, html, css, cycle

I'm using Cycle2 carousel plugin my all images width are different that's why I want to centered my images but there is something that I wonder is if  my parent wrapper width is 900px(for example) and if my images aren't 900px than it will be centered ?

I mean if my images bigger than 900px than do nothing (don't centered)but if my images smaller than 900px than centered them

let me show you on image
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('.mySlideShow').cycle({
    next: "#single-right",
    pauseOnHover: true,
    pager: "#single-pager",
    pagerTemplate: "<a href='#'><img src='{{src}}' width=48 height=48></a>",
    prev: "#single-left",
  });
  
 
});
```

```css
.single-gallery{
  width:800px;
 height:640px;
  position:relative;
}
.cycle-slideshow img {
  height:494px;
  width:auto;
}

#single-pager a img {
  width: 49.3px !important;
  height:49.3px !important;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#single-pager a.cycle-pager-active img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#single-left,
#single-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#single-left {
  left: 0;
}

#single-right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<div class="single-gallery">
  <div class="mySlideShow">
    <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/07/20/40/candy-1961536_960_720.jpg">
    <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/11/11/33/cake-1971552_960_720.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png">
   
  <div id="single-pager" class="center external"></div>
    
  <div id="single-next-prev">
    <span id="single-left">Prev</span>
    <span id="single-right">Next</span>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to center images bigger than `900px`? In your snippet example I dont see small images...

Comment: Your snippet contains all images of same size right.?

Comment: no all images widh are different size

Comment: @lonut what do you mean ? because my wrapper  is already 900px but if possible the images which is bigger than 900px can be centered

Comment: I do not understand where the problem is here...if the wrapper is `900px` and the image is `900px`, it should fit the container right?

Comment: I want to centered images is the problem actually my english is not enought to understand each other sorry about it

Comment: Add two images, one with how the slideshow looks now and the other how do you want it to look please. Also, I see the wrapper in your code is `800px`, not `900px`.

Comment: I edited my answer for example last image is small and I want to center last image center of wrapper http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/MpvymG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.3.9/css/lightgallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<div class="single-gallery">
  <div class="mySlideShow">
    <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/07/20/40/candy-1961536_960_720.jpg">
    <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/11/11/33/cake-1971552_960_720.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png">

  <div id="single-pager" class="center external"></div>

  <div id="single-next-prev">
    <span id="single-left">Prev</span>
    <span id="single-right">Next</span>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8njfur1g/show/)